# how can I connect to an onpremise sever through firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless-architecture

I'm trying to fetch data from a onpremise server through my firebase function.
This server has an intranet ip which is not accessible externally.
So, is it possible to get data from the onpremise server, which is not even connected to the internet.

Comment: Cloud Functions execute on the Google Cloud Platform infrastructure and if you want a Cloud Function to get data from a server you need to have it connected to internet (or to export its data on a machine that is connected to internet)

Comment: Sounds like an answer Renaud! @Akhil: if the intranet server can't be reached from the public internet, the only way to access its data in Cloud Functions is if you pass that data in when you call the function from a device that *does* have access to the intranet server.

Comment: Agreed! I think I got my answer. Thank you @RenaudTarnec!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions execute on the Google Cloud Platform infrastructure and if you want a Cloud Function to get data from a server, you need to have it connected to internet (or to export its data to a machine that is connected to internet).